# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "NO" when expecting one of the following

Tags: sql, plsql

I am getting this error while trying to execute this PL/SQL

"PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "NO" when expecting one of the following"

```
Begin 
Execute Immediate 'Delete Dimension_Alias where member_name !='No Project'';
END;
```

Help appreciated.

Regards,
Ragav.

Comment: Even stackoverflow code highlight has pointed you to a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the single quotes:

```
Execute Immediate 'Delete Dimension_Alias where member_name <> ''No Project''';
```

In SQL, adjacent single quotes in a string are treated as a single quote.